# Qt5.4 for WP8.1 QFileDialog doesn't work

Tags: qt, windows-phone-8, qml, qt5, qt5.4

I want to know how to show a picture picker? I had set the capabilities:

```
WINRT_MANIFEST.capabilities += documentsLibrary removableStorage
```

I test `QFileDialog`, but it does not show anything. Is there a document path for WP 8.1?

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: See http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_get_and_edit_gallery_images_in_Qt_and_WP

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this ? [photoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Your answer is not related to Qt.